# as fast as or as fast

Tags: sentence-construction

Rohan is _________ or perhaps faster than Suresh.
a)as fast as
b)as fast

now I think as fast as should be the answer, but the answer given is as fast.

can you help me out, please?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You are right. The option (as far as) is true, and the answer key of the book is wrong.

When we make comparisons between two things, it should be this way [X1 as **adjective** as X2]. 
Otherwise it would be false.

Answer (score 1):

Both forms are possible.

Using "as fast as" is perhaps more logical. But we do expect a noun to follow "as" and so this form doesn't flow well.

Using "as fast" sounds smoother. But it is logically wrong.  (but English is not a problem to be solved by math and logic)

Rephrasing to avoid the problem is probably the best solution:

> Suresh is no faster than Rohan.